# Half-installed package - kibana

Tags: apt, package-management

I find troubles installing/removing/upgrading a half-installed package kibana. I probably edited kibana.yml file the wrong way and cant manage to get it working back.

```
[09:32] ***-VM:cache$ sudo apt-get --purge remove kibana
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kibana*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 124 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error processing package kibana (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
kibana
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it before trying to remove it? As the error message is suggesting as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you can use to resolve this situation:

1. reinstalling and then removing

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall kibana
   sudo apt-get remove kibana
   ```
2. single remove without purge

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove kibana
   ```
3. force installing and removing

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   sudo apt-get remove --purge kibana
   ```
4. force removing by `dpkg`

   ```
   sudo dpkg -r --force kibana
   ```